# SQL Server: How to add Count to nested Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, count

I have a stored procedure that fetches data from three separate tables using the following query which works as intended.

How can I add a Count to each level so that I know how many items there are selected for A., B. and C. ?
I tried adding "`COUNT(*) AS volume`" but then I get an error that some column references are invalid.

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT      A.itemID,
                A.title,
                A.sortID,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.modDate, 106) AS modDate,
                A.modBy,
                (
                    SELECT      B.itemID,
                                B.parentID,
                                B.title,
                                B.sortID,
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), B.modDate, 106) AS modDate,
                                B.modBy,
                                (
                                    SELECT      C.itemID,
                                                C.parentID,
                                                C.title,
                                                C.sortID,
                                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), C.modDate, 106) AS modDate,
                                                C.modBy
                                    FROM        ORG_Nav3 C
                                    WHERE       C.parentID = B.itemID
                                    AND         C.logStatus = 'active'
                                    ORDER BY    C.sortID, C.title
                                    FOR XML PATH('nav3'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                                )
                    FROM        ORG_Nav2 B
                    WHERE       B.parentID = A.itemID
                    AND         B.logStatus = 'active'
                    ORDER BY    B.sortID, B.title
                    FOR XML PATH('nav2'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                )
    FROM        ORG_Nav1 A
    WHERE       A.logStatus = 'active'
    ORDER BY    A.sortID, A.title
    FOR XML PATH('nav'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')

END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: The query is working, I just don't know how to add the count here.

Comment: Your query might work, but it is long and contains many parts that are not relevant to your question.  This makes it hard for people to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. I am not expecting that someone rewrites the whole query. For this question looking at the last nested query would help me already as the other levels follow the same structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get what you want using window functions.  Note that the counts will be repeated for each element, though:

```
SELECT      A.itemID,
            A.title,
            A.sortID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), A.modDate, 106) AS modDate,
            A.modBy,
            COUNT(*) OVER () as CNT
            (
                SELECT      B.itemID,
                            B.parentID,
                            B.title,
                            B.sortID,
                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), B.modDate, 106) AS modDate,
                            B.modBy,
                            COUNT(*) OVER () as CNT
                            (
                                SELECT      C.itemID,
                                            C.parentID,
                                            C.title,
                                            C.sortID,
                                            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), C.modDate, 106) AS modDate,
                                            C.modBy,
                                            COUNT(*) OVER () as CNT
                                FROM        ORG_Nav3 C
                                WHERE       C.parentID = B.itemID
                                AND         C.logStatus = 'active'
                                ORDER BY    C.sortID, C.title
                                FOR XML PATH('nav3'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
                            )
                FROM        ORG_Nav2 B
                WHERE       B.parentID = A.itemID
                AND         B.logStatus = 'active'
                ORDER BY    B.sortID, B.title
                FOR XML PATH('nav2'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
            )
FROM        ORG_Nav1 A
WHERE       A.logStatus = 'active'
ORDER BY    A.sortID, A.title
FOR XML PATH('nav'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon - this is great ! I will accept as soon as I can. :)